# Codes not being update while coding PHP

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xampp, google-chrome-devtools, phpstorm

For some reason, XAMPP won't update my files. The codes are different when I open it up in vscode and different in Chrome Debugger.
[image: This] This is the snap of the codes from chrome tools. [image: This] This is the snap of the same file from VSCODE. I've checked the code in Atom text editor and the codes match with VSCODE. But for some reason, the codes are not being updated in my XAMPP server. I've restarted my computer, turned all the XAMPP services on and off multiple times. Nothing has worked so far.

---

Edit:
This problem is not specific to vscode and XAMPP, its the same with ```php -S localhost:4000``` (i don't know the name of this) and PHPStorm.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're code gets "painted" once and I don't think you're calling it correctly to recall the code.